# My letters are white! I can't see anything of What I'm typing, how do I change this?

Tags: windows-8, themes

I don't know what it is that I did, I was trying some new themes in my Windows so I installed this patch that was needed to do it, then I fiddled with some themes. I don't where in the process but somehow my letters are almost white (very light gray), I can barely see what I'm typing right now.

Changing only the back panel of the windows would already help. Although I now returned to the default Windows theme, somehow the programs menu of the taskbar (I use Classic Shell) is still black from a theme I tried and it's actually much more readable than the white background, which is barely readable at all. I'm on Win 8 Pro x64.

Comment: Sorry I could swear I had put this info in here. It's Win 8 Pro x64. It doesn't have this "window color" window. I've seen that in another answer here in superuser, it seemed that it would be helpful

Comment: Was it an installable package? If so, try uninstalling it via the `Programs and Features` control panel.

Comment: I've removed everything already. I tried learning about Resource Hacker but I'm not an expert and I'm afraid I can ruin things up even more and even then, I didn't find the system folder for font coloring. I've tried locating where it is in the system with RegScanner but I'm also not exactly an expert on it so I couldn't find a fix this way either